# Best openid implementation

Tags: openid, usability

I think OpenId has many things for it. But the biggest beef I have with it, is usability. Especially the technically non-savvy have dificulty understanding that the need to select a "provider" to login. Stackoverflows login implementation is quite good, but I think it would cost me quite some explaining to get my mother to use here gmail account to register/login to another site...

So the question is: Does anynone know OpenId register/login implemtantions which are more usable than Stackoverflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RPXNow](http://www.rpxnow.com/) is a paid service (with a free level) that has a nice UI.
Then there's [this one](http://openidux.dotnetopenauth.net/) which is free and open source, but not as polished.  But it did pass the "my mom could log in without help" test.

Comment: Seems like rpxnow is the best currently.. I'm going to test it on my mom soon!